# JavaScript: variable assignemnt in for statement | precede or inside

Tags: javascript

I have seen both....variable declaration in or before the for statement.  Which is better?  Here is an example snippet.

```
MC.initAll = function() {
    var iterate = [MC, Su], 
        l = iterate.length, 
        i, 
        key;
    for( i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
        for( key in iterate[i]) {
            if( iterate[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && iterate[i][key].hasOwnProperty("init") ) {
                iterate[i][key].init();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Pros of putting at top of function outside the for statement:**

- less code due to using the same var statement
- already hoisted , js does not have to
- internal working made more explicit
- will pass jshint.com

**Pros of putting in the for statement**

- easy visual inspect to verify declaration took place in function

Comment: You almost have close-vote priviledges, you should know this question is not constructive.

Comment: Since this is an opinion question, with no real fact or reference-based answer, it's probably not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is personal style.  Which is "better" is purely a matter of opinion.  The javascript interpreter will hoist all variable definitions to the start of the variable block no matter where the `var` statement appears.

I personally like to put my var in the `for` loop just so there is no accidental forgetting and using an implicit global variable, but that's just a personal style choice.  I know others like all variables declared explicitly at the start of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I declare my variable before the assing it in the for loop

```
var i, j; 
for (i = 0, j = x.length; i < j; i = i+1){
     the loop ... 
}
```

that way i only declare my counter 1 time throughou my code and reset it at will. 
If i nee to keep the counter value i declare another value where i put my counter value

Comment: if i see that i need to have my length more than once you declare it outside ... my answer was more centered toward the counter more than the length of j. However you cannot suit many cases with one method i think. And the length of j is only executed once since its only the loop declarative section.